# Can python requests package functioning as VPN?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ssh, python-requests

Some website has different appearance when accessed in different locations. I am doing a project on ssh with Linux system, requiring me to scrape data from the same website supposing my location is in different countries.

I have tried the package `requests` (I retrieved the proxy IP from https://free-proxy-list.net):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.ebay.com'        
proxies = {'https:':'http://' + some_proxy_IP), 
           'http':'http://' + some_proxy_IP_2)}
u_a = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36"
page = requests.get(url, proxies,headers={"USER-AGENT":u_a})

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
p_soup = soup.prettify()
```

However, the websites it retrieves with different proxies are all the same as I retrieve from my physical location.

Am I using requests in the correct way? Or should I be using requests here?

If not, will `NetworkManager` fit my purpose? Or any other packages/techniques (even JS is welcome) are recommended for this purpose?